# How to import a CSV with a last empty column into R?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, read.csv, citations

I wrote an `R` script to make some scientometric analyses of [Journal Citation Report](https://jcr.clarivate.com) data (JCR), which I have been using and updating in the past years.

Today, Clarivate has just introduced some changes in its database and now the exported CSV file contains one last empty column, which spoils my script. Because of this last empty column, `read.csv` automatically assumes that the first column contains the row names.

As before, there is also one first useless row, which is automatically removed in my script with `skip = 1`.

One simple solution to this "empty column situation" would be to manually remove this last column in Excel, and then proceed with my script as usual.

However, is there a way to add this removal to my script using `base R`?

The beginning of my script is:

```
    jcreco = read.csv("data/jcr ecology 2020.csv",
    na = "n/a", skip = 1, header = T)
```

The original CSV file downloaded from JCR is available in my [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/azcasibikjkeks6/jcr%20ecology%202020.csv?dl=0).

Could you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that empty column doesn't have a header. If they had only had the extra comma at the end of the header line this probably wouldn't be as messy. But you can also do a bit of column shuffling with `fill=TRUE`. For example

```
dd <- read.table("~/../Downloads/jcr ecology 2020.csv", sep=",", 
   skip=2, fill=T, header=T, row.names=NULL)
names(dd)[-ncol(dd)] <- names(dd)[-1]
dd <- dd[,-ncol(dd)]
```

This reads in the data but puts the rows names in the data.frame and fills the last column with NA. Then you shift all the column names over to the left and drop the last column.

Comment: This is the short summary of the analysis, using the script updated with your help: https://rpubs.com/marmello77/677911

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.

1. Read the data as text lines;
2. Discard the first line;
3. Remove the end comma with `sub`;
4. Create a text connection;
5. And read in the data from the connection.

The variable `fl` holds the file, on my disk I had to set the directory.

```
fl <- "jcr_ecology_2020.csv"
txt <- readLines(fl)
txt <- txt[-1]
txt <- sub(",$", "", txt)
con <- textConnection(txt)
df1 <- read.csv(con)
close(con)
head(df1)
```